# What is the difference between the numerical range, and the joint numerical range?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I know the joint numerical range is the generalization of the numerical range, but when searching up the definitions of both, I dont see a difference. Can someone help?

Comment: Can you point out the definitions that you found to be identical?

Comment: See "https://repository.uwyo.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?referer=https://www.google.com/&httpsredir=1&article=1037&context=ela"